# How to merge ReactJS project svelte? Or How to insert .svelte file into ReactJs project?

Tags: reactjs, svelte, svelte-component

How to merge `node_module`, project dependencies, of both Svelte and ReactJs?

I've seen guides showing how to include ReactJS file into a Svelte app

```
<SvelteComponent this={First} {...this.props}/>
```

That produces the following error:

> Constructor is not a Constructor error

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You say include React in Svelte but do you mean Svelte in React app? You example leads me to think so.

Comment: Cosmin Staicu , I installed a basic react-app and remove the package-lock.json file and edited the dependencies change the dev dependencies devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rollup": "^1.12.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.0.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^4.0.4",
    "svelte": "^3.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1"
  } then i run npm install --save react-svelte-component --force

Comment: Michael i said i included a .svelte file into react-app the project compile but when i impotred SvelteComponent into js file and tried to run <SvelteComponent >by calling constructor of SvelteComponent in render(return()) method it cant able to identify the constructor

Answer (score 1):

here is an example of including a svelte component in react. It been written by Rich Harris author of svelte:

https://github.com/Rich-Harris/react-svelte

Answer (score 0):

Svelte and React are not compatible to import and use the other framework component directly.

It is definitely possible to create a Svelte app inside of a React app or vice-versa though.

You would have to instantiate the app like normal inside of the other app. [The Svelte docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#Creating_a_component) show how you can bind a Svelte app to a DOM node, which you can include in a React component. Make sure you also add the DOM node inside of that component, such as `<div id="svelte-app" />`.