# How to Rendering React App inside Svelte App or Rendering Svelte App inside React App?

Tags: reactjs, svelte

How to use svelte file into react app

I tried importing SvelteComponent into ReactJS app.

```
import SvelteComponent from 'react-svelte-component';
import First from './First.svelte';
<SvelteComponent this={First} value={this.state.value}/>
```

Svelte component should be reflected on web

Comment: You already asked this question about more or less the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283544/how-to-merge-reactjs-project-svelte-or-how-to-insert-svelte-file-into-reactjs please edit that one and make it more precise. There is a repo from the creator of Svelte for using svelte in React. Try to start with that and show the code you've used https://github.com/Rich-Harris/react-svelte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge ReactJS project svelte? Or How to insert .svelte file into ReactJs project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57283544/how-to-merge-reactjs-project-svelte-or-how-to-insert-svelte-file-into-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to render somehow source of `.js`, and render `html` with `#id` or `.class` that identifies where another app should be rendered.

Then you can keep svelte and react app in the one repository or in different repositories. All you need is rendering a valid link to another app .js file.

You might even:
* render react inside Angular app
* use jquery inside Svelte or React or Angular app

Actually, you can get issues with css-styles overlap. It’s really pain. But you could use these hints for minimizing css issues.
https://github.com/bsurai/building-web-embedded-apps